# Rename bunch of files in bash script

Tags: string, bash, file

I have some files with names which contains date, but this date part is in wrong format, and I need to change it. Example files:

```
foo-1-21-01-16.tar
foo-1-22-01-16.tar
foobar-1-21-01-16.tar
foobar-1-22-01-16.tar
```

Result that I want to have should look like this:

```
foo-1-16-01-21.tar
foo-1-16-01-22.tar
foobar-1-16-01-21.tar
foobar-1-16-01-22.tar
```

So, what I want to do is to change place of "day" part with place of "year" part. But I can't figure out how to do this. There is more than a few files, so I can't do this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would suggest you use AWK. Example:

```
  echo "foo-1-21-01-16.tar" | awk -F'[-.]' '{printf "bar-%s-%s-%s-%s.%s", $2, $5, $4, $3, $6 }'
```

will result in `bar-1-16-01-21.tar`. The -F parameter tells awk to split each line of input on `-` or `.`. After the split, `$1 = foo`, `$5 = year`, etc. use `print` to recompose a filename with each field in another order.

From a **bash script**, iterate through your files, use the above command to create the new filename, then use `mv` to rename the file. Tell me if you need a code example.

Comment: Iterating though files, or using mv isn't a problem. I don't know much about awk, and I just couldn't figure out this part about switching places in file name. I can now work with what you gave me. Thanks! :)